# VueJS Loading More Blog Posts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working with the Wordpress API and am trying to sort out a new blog system. I am a little new to VueJS and am curious how this sort of thing is handled.

I am able to load the initial blog posts like so:

```js
let blogApiURL = 'https://element5.wpengine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=12'

let authorApiURL = "https://element5.wpengine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users"

let newPage = 1;

let posts = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    authors: null,
    currentAuthor: '23',
    posts: null,
    pageNumber: newPage,
    range: 0
  },

  created: function() {
    this.fetchAuthorData()
    this.fetchBlogData()
  },

  watch: {
    currentAuthor: 'fetchBlogData'
  },

  methods: {
    fetchAuthorData: function() {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      let self = this
      xhr.open('GET', authorApiURL)
      xhr.onload = function() {
        self.authors = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
      }
      xhr.send()
    },
    fetchBlogData: function() {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      let self = this
      xhr.open('GET', blogApiURL + '&page=' + self.pageNumber + '&author=' + self.currentAuthor)
      xhr.onload = function() {
        self.posts = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
      }
      xhr.send()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="author-toggle-wrap post">
    <select v-model="currentAuthor" name="authors" id="author-select">
        <template v-for="author in authors">
            <option
              :id="author.id"
              :value="author.id"
              name="author.id">{{ author.name }}</option>
        </template>
      </select>
  </div>

  <div class="post-wrapper">
    <p>Current Author: <code>{{ currentAuthor }}</code></p>
    <template v-for="post in posts">
    <div class="post">
     <h2 class="post-title" v-html="post.title.rendered"></h2>
          <template v-if="post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']">
            <a v-if="post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes['large']" :href="post.link">
      <img :src="post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes['large'].source_url" />
     </a>
          <a :href="post.link" v-else>
            <img src="https://element5.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/wp-starter-theme/dist/images/default-thumb.jpg" />
          </a>
          </template>
    <div class="excerpt" v-if="post.excerpt.rendered" v-html="post.excerpt.rendered"></div>
    <div class="entry-meta" v-if="post._embedded.author[0]">
      <a class="author-wrap" :href="post._embedded.author[0].link"><img class="avatar" :src="post._embedded.author[0].avatar_urls['48']" />by&nbsp; {{ post._embedded.author[0].name }} </a>
      <a class="button read-more" :href="post.link">Read More &raquo;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </template>
</div>
</div>
```

This works great! Made me super excited about Vue and its potential!

I am trying to sort out loading more posts without it killing the posts I already loaded. I have started down the following path:

```js
Vue.component('sub-blog', {
  template: '<div>On Each Click Load Next 12 posts here!</div>'
})

let newPosts = new Vue({
  el: '#load-more-posts',
  data: {
    range: 0
  },
  methods: {
    addMorePosts: function() {
      newPage++
      this.range += 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="load-more-posts">
  <sub-blog v-for="n in range"></sub-blog>
  <div class="load-more">
    <button v-on:click="addMorePosts" class="btn">Load More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

After much monkeying around I think I need a little assistance sorting how to simply load the dynamic data into the component properly. Its loading new components on click which is cool, but I need to fire off a new api get request with the updated page number and essentially add the exact same layout as the initally loaded posts.

Here is a link to a pen: https://codepen.io/trafficdaddy/pen/YEwNKy?editors=1010

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to have the button that fetches more posts in a separate component. You can do it a bit like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVdpLb?editors=1010

```
addMorePosts: function(){
this.pageNumber += 1
this.range += 1
this.fetchBlogData();
}
```

Just have the button in the same component and then push new posts coming from the api to the array.

Comment: I see what you are doing here. I was doing something nearly identical, but this acts more like pagination...it does not retain the original posts. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @JoethaCoder to retain the original posts you will need to push to the end of the array instead of replacing it

Comment: To clarify then should I make the initial posts property in the data object an empty array and then push the initial call to that?

Comment: Yes initialposts should be an empty array and on fetchBlogData you add new posts to the end of the array. So on the initial call it's the same as your first attempt but afterwards you end up with 20, 30 and so on posts on the array

Comment: Yay that totally worked! I had to add a quick for loop to move the items from the initial array to the new posts array but no biggie there! I updated your pen here: [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVdpLb?editors=1010] thanks for the help!